# AWK get strings after floating delimiters

Tags: awk

I need to validate the output of a script that prints the variables out of order like this.

proc: 123 id: 456 zzz: aaa xxx: ccc

xxx: ccc id: 654 proc: 321 zzz: aaa yyy:111

...

I need to get "proc" value and "id" but as position change I'm not getting how to do it with awk.
If the fields kept the same position like this

proc: 123 id: 456 zzz: aaa xxx: ccc

this would do the trick

awk '$2 == "123" && $4 != "456" {print "something"}'

but as the fields are dynamic I'm a bit stuck

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: can any of the 'variables' or values contain embedded spaces, tabs or colons (other than the trailing colon for 'variables')? what exactly is `print "something"` supposed to generate? are you only looking to print the results to stdout or do you need to capture them in `bash` for later/follow-on processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++)                         # iterate all awk default-separated fields
        if($i~/^(proc|id):$/)                 # looking for proc: and id:
            a[$i]=$(i+1)                      # get value to an indexed array element
    if(a["proc:"]=="123"&&a["id:"]=="456") {  # once you got both
        print                                 # print
        delete a                              # delete a for next round
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
proc: 123 id: 456 zzz: aaa xxx: ccc
```

It fails if the data is in fact: `proc:123 id:456 ...`.

Comment: It works great, did a few mods to do what I needed. tks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Once you use this code to isolate out the field values, then you can perform any form of filtering logic to it. It can even handle multi-byte unicode data within the field values.

```
{m,g}awk '
BEGIN {                              
     _ =  index(FS="[ \t:]+", OFS)              
    __ = """(proc|id)[ \t]*[:][ \t]*[^ \t]+" 
}  NF  *              ( \                                                                    
 $!NF  = sprintf("%.0s%.0s row: %5.f | proc: %6s | id: %6s | orig $0:\f %s", ___=$+__,   
   NF *=         gsub(__,"\26& \36")* gsub("(^|\36)[^\26]*(\26|$)","")*\  
                 gsub( "^" FS "|" FS "$",        "")^!_, 
   NR,           $(_^(/^i/)*_), $(_^(/^p/)*_), ___))^!_'
```

—————————————————————————————————

```
 row:     1 | proc:    123 | id:    456 | orig $0:
                                                   proc: 123 id: 456 zzz: aaa xxx: ccc
 row:     3 | proc:    321 | id:    654 | orig $0:
                                                   xxx: ccc id: 654 proc: 321 zzz: aaa yyy:111
 
 row:     4 | proc: 123뀿abc | id: 456_987 | orig $0:
                                                       proc: 123뀿abc id: 456_987 zzz: aaa xxx: ccc
```